# Embedding youtube video with exact time using Spring and Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, video, youtube, thymeleaf

I have an issue when I try to embed a youtube video with exact time in a Java Project with Spring and Thymeleaf.

**1/ Working scenario:**
When I try to embed a normal youtube video it works:
In the Controller I have this:
*article.setVideo(video);*
Where video is the end String of the youtube video:

Example video link: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/s39mNwFuQDQ`
Here the value of **video** will be:  **s39mNwFuQDQ**

Now in the html Thymeleaf view I have:
[html Thymeleaf view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xdx7z.jpg)

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" th:src="@{https://www.youtube.com/embed/{url} (url=${article.video})}"   frameborder="0" alt="no video attached" allowfullscreen="1"></iframe>
```

It takes the saved video String, concatenates it to `https://www.youtube.com/embed/` and it is working just fine.

**2/ Non-working scenario:**
When I try to do the same, but with youtube video with exact time – it is not working:

In the Controller I have this:

*article.setVideo(video + "?start=" + extOptions);*

Where:

*video* - is a String;
*extOptions* is a String.

As a result I get a String

Example: `https://www.youtube.com /embed/s39mNwFuQDQ?start=212` 
**video** is - **s39mNwFuQDQ**
**extOptions** is - **212**

Now in article.getVideo() I have : **s39mNwFuQDQ?start=212**  - this is saved in Database just fine.

In the Thymeleaf html view I still have the same code.
Unfortunately my video is not displayed at all this time in the Browser (tried different browsers).

When I try an exact display of the video like this:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" th:src="@{https://www.youtube.com/embed/s39mNwFuQDQ?start=212}" frameborder="0" alt="no video attached" allowfullscreen="1">
```

It is working and video is displayed and starts from 212 second.

What could be the problem here ?

I tried some escaping for the ? mark, some pattern quote(regex escape) – but this does not help, these only fill the String with unwanted characters.

Any ideas how to solve the issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thymeleaf is escaping the question mark (as it should in this case).  If you view the source, you'd see it's replacing the `?` with `%3F`. The way you should be doing this is keeping the start in a different variable, and building the url like this:

```
th:src="@{https://www.youtube.com/embed/{url} (url=${article.video}, start=${article.start})}"
```

If that's not an option, you can create your url as a string instead, but then you are opening yourself up to certain attacks (if you can receive untrusted input for video urls).

```
th:src="${'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + url}"
```

---

*Answer Edit* -- if the controller options are set like this:

```
article.setVideo(video);           // example: video equals: s39mNwFuQDQ
article.setVideoLink(extOptions);  // example: extOptions equals: 212
```

The complete syntax of the Thymeleaf is:

```
<!-- Generated url: https://www.youtube.com/embed/s39mNwFuQDQ?start=212 -->
<iframe width="560" height="315" th:src="@{https://www.youtube.com/embed/{url}(url=${article.video}, start=${article.videoLink})}" frameborder="1" alt="no video attached" allowfullscreen="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Many thanks Metroids: I did like you recommended, but still have the issue. There is an improvement though - now the video is displayed, but it starts from the beginning. Tried different browsers to avoid caching. Now in DB i see the 2 variables: for video I have : s39mNwFuQDQ and for start as per your recommendation: ?start=212.    The improvement is now that I do have the video, but does not start from the set time, but from beginning. Can you suggest what could be the issue this time ?

Comment: I believe in this case article.video is added, but the article.start is skipped. How to add it to the link ?

Comment: What is the thymeleaf html are you using (exactly), and what is the direct html output?

Comment: It looks like this: just as per your recommendation: `<iframe width="560" height="315" th:src="@{https://www.youtube.com/embed/{url}(url=${article.video}, videoLink=${article.videoLink})}" frameborder="0" alt="no video attached" allowfullscreen="0"></iframe>`   (videoLink is the one, instead of start - I just had it configured previously) So in exact example: article.video has : s39mNwFuQDQ   and article.videoLink has ?start=212.  It displays the video but starts from the beginning. Tried different browsers and videos to avoid caching and license restrictions.

Comment: In the Controller I store it like this: article.setVideoLink("?start=" + extOptions);   where extOptions is the time in seconds, as a String. Everything is stored valid. It seems to me that the videoLink variable is not engaged, by the way according to the syntax - it looks like it is not declared, but I do not know the right syntax in this case.

Comment: Why do you use videoLink=${article.videoLink} instead of start=${article.videoLink}?  The text "start="  has to match the parameter in the url.  If you use videoLink=${article.videoLink}, then the full url will be https://www.youtube.com/embed/s39mNwFuQDQ?videoLink=212, which of course youtube doesn't understand -- it has to be https://www.youtube.com/embed/s39mNwFuQDQ?start=212

Comment: Wow thanks a lot Metroids. You saved the day for me. It works just fine now. I built the wrong link, because I don't know the syntax and mistunderstood you. I guess a wider answer was needed. I must admit this Thymeleaf syntax is rather weird and specific - but once you know it can do great things easily. I cannot vote, as I do not have points enough, but I will mark your answer,as solution, though I will enhance your answer with the explanations to make it more understandable for someone who may have encounter such an issue. Great thanks for your help.